# Improper configuration of mysql database in django

Tags: python, django

Please, I was trying to install a database into my django environment. So in the settings.py file,
I entered the following given that I am used to the MySQL database..
ENGINE: django.db.backends.mysql
NAME: /Applications/MAMP/db/ # this is because my 'mysql' is stored in that location on my mac machine 
USER: herodb #I just gave it this name to be used in django..

Now, I already have databases in my 'mysql' because I have been using it for other projects. so, i dont have to create any databases. Yet when i ran the command : python manage.py syncdb, I get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

A careful look at this error, I discovered this : **raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb**

According to the steps I took earlier, could anyone direct me to where I might have done the imporper configuration? I don't have any sql called MySQLdb. So, how do I fix this error?

Comment: You need the name of the database in your configuration, nor the place where the binary or the data is stored.

Comment: Give us a copy of your django database config, without any sensetive data, so that we can better judge.

Comment: @Matthias, my database is in the db directory of the MAMP directory in the Applications directory. Do I need to go any further to get the binary?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things:

1) Your DB settings should look like this for MySQL:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'yourdbname',
        'USER': 'yourdbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'yourdbpassword',
    }
}
```

2) The traceback tells you you're missing the python mysql library for interfacing with MySQL. Install this using: `sudo easy_install MySQL-python` or `sudo pip install MySQL-python`.

Comment: I guess my path might be wrong. my 'mysql' folder is in the db folder in the MAMP which is in the Applications directory yet when I run it, i get this : sudo: mysql/: command not found

cd /Applications/MAMP/db/ sudo mysql 
any help on getting this right? I have never had to use mysql from the command line. only on the myphp admin..now am stuck

Comment: No-one is asking you to run mysql from the command line at all. You need to run `pip` or `easy-install`.

Comment: Django needs MySQL-python to interface with mysql, all you need to do is install it and Django can then talk to your MySQL database.